# Form looks like a balloon

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am just trying to create a form control in winform in .net with custom shaped of balloon shape.
There is need of a balloon tooltip which is transparent and I can put buttons on tooltip,but
tooltip in .net does not provide facality that we can put the buttons on tooltip control so
I want to make a form control looks like a balloon tooltip and so I can put buttons on that form looking like a tooltip.But I cannot show window form control look like a balloon tooltip.
So what should I do??
I tried in one way that I create a image in powerpoint of balloon shape and set it to as background image of form property.But there is no solution with that.

Comment: This isn't a simple thing to do in Winforms - you HAVE to create a custom control/window of some kind as the other answers have suggested. YES, this will involve some work.

Comment: @Harikrishna - please don't keep asking the same question. If something is unclear, edit the question to clarify it. I have merged the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

The Control class supports a BackColor with an alpha < 255, it is automatic.  It asks the Parent to draw itself to produce the background of the control, then draws itself on top of that.  However, you'll want a top-level window for a balloon.  That's a window type that can arbitrarily overlap another window and isn't confined by the client area of an underlying window.  It has no Parent.  A ToolTip is such a window.

The only control available in Windows Forms that can be an top-level window is a Form.  Problem is: the transparency trick no longer works.  Since a top-level window doesn't have a Parent, there isn't any obvious window to ask to draw the background.  It could be many windows, belonging to other processes.  You can get transparency in a Form with its TransparencyKey property.  But that's a "hard" transparency, equivalent to an alpha of 0.  You probably want a soft one.  Another nasty problem is that drawing anti-aliased (ClearType) text no longer works since there is no reliable background pixel color anymore.

Long story short: you can't make this work well unless you confine the balloon to the client area of a form.  A control, not a form.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to hook on the Paint event of the control and draw the Visual of the button there.